# Using sbt-native-packager, how can I simply prepend a directory to my bash script's ${app_classpath}?

Tags: bash, scala, sbt, config, sbt-native-packager

My project uses **sbt-native-packager** with **packageArchetype.java_application**.
During *sbt stage* I have a task that generates some final Typesafe style configuration file that I then copy to:

```
target/universal/stage/conf/application.conf
```

I'd like to prepend this directory to the runtime classpath in the bash script, and am looking for the simplest way to do that. I'd hate to maintain a separate *src/main/templates/bash-template* for something so simple, and am not seeing exactly how to go about it otherwise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Define a package mapping

```
mappings in Universal <+= (packageBin in Compile, sourceDirectory ) map { 
    (_, src) =>
    // we are using the reference.conf as default application.conf
    // the user can override settings here
    val conf = src / "main" / "resources" / "reference.conf"
    conf -> "conf/application.conf"
}
```

Create a **jvmopts** in **src/universal/conf** with

```
-Dconfig.file=/<installation-path>/conf/application.conf
```

Add to **build.sbt**

```
bashScriptConfigLocation := Some("${app_home}/../conf/jvmopts")
```

Example for server_archetype:
Follow the [example application](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/application-conf). A bit of description can be found [here](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples#application-configuration).

**Long answer**

Changing the classpath is not supported directly by the sbt-native-packager, because it can cause problems like

- classpath ordering
- security issues

Like Typesafe Config, most libraries which use config files, provide a parameter to define the location of the configuration file. Use the parameters describe [in the documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior).

It seems your are trying to run a *server*, which means you can use the

```
packageArchetype.java_server
```

which is designed to read external configurations. Take a look at the [example application](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/application-conf) how to use it.

Comment: instead of creating `src/universal/conf/jvmopts` the following code can be added to `build.sbt`: `bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Dconfig.file=${app_home}/../conf/application.conf""""`

Comment: To make the generated bat file works on windows, also add the following to `build.sbt`. 
`batScriptExtraDefines += """call :add_java "-Dconfig.file=%APP_HOME%\conf\application.conf""""`

Answer (score 6):

The following setting:

```
scriptClasspath in bashScriptDefines ~= (cp => "../conf" +: cp),
```

Allows you to do exactly what you need.

In this specific example I prepend the "../conf" directory to the classpath entries.

Also, you need to import the following configuration keys to your build SBT:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys.bashScriptDefines
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys.scriptClasspath
```

Comment: N.B. it is possible to prepend relative paths only

Comment: In SBT 1.2 I only needed one import: `import NativePackagerHelper._`

Answer (score 2):

The question you asked in the title is a bit different from the description. I am answering the question in the title here - i.e. how can you prepend a directory into the classpath:

This is very hacky and brittle in that it will probably break if/when the sbt-native-packager makes changes to how the script is generated, but for now it works for me:

```
private lazy val ClasspathPattern = "declare -r app_classpath=\"(.*)\"\n".r

bashScriptDefines :=  bashScriptDefines.value.map {
                              case ClasspathPattern(classpath) => "declare -r app_classpath=\"/path/to/some/external/lib/*:" + classpath + "\"\n"
                              case _@entry => entry
                          },
```

Comment: That's what I need to do.  Has a better way arisen in the last five years?